# What is "taxi speed" for an Airbus?

Tags: airline-operations, airbus, taxiing

In the FCOM we can see a lot of "taxi speed", for example after landing:

> AT TAXI SPEED, ALL REVERSER LEVERS......STOW

But what is taxi speed? Is there any definition or particular number? 40kt or 30kt?

Answer (score 6):

The Flight Crew Training Manual (FCTM) defines taxi speed as a ground speed of up to **30 kt**:

> **Taxi Speed and Braking**
>
> On long, straight taxiways, and with no ATC or other ground traffic constraints, the PF
> should allow the aircraft to accelerate to 30 kt, and should then use one smooth brake
> application to decelerate to 10 kt. The PF should not ”ride” the brakes. The GS indication on the ND should be used to assess taxi speed.

<sup>(Airbus A320 FCTM - Normal Operations - Taxi)</sup>